# Wrong URL found in Svelte Named Form Action RequestEvent

Tags: javascript, forms, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to throw a redirect inside a named form action for login process, but instead of the redirect I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')
    at Module.redirect (eval at instantiateModule (file:///[PROJECT_DIR]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:55971:28), <anonymous>:56:61)
```

When I logged out the value of the `url.searchParams.get('redirectTo')` it came to be `null`.
And when I logged the full url instead, it came out to be `"http://localhost:5173/login?/login"` when it was supposed to be `"http://localhost:5173/login?redirectTo=/branches"`. And this is clearly the **named** form action path.

The form action code looks like this:

```js
export const actions = {
    login: async ({ cookies, request, url }) => {
          //...
          if (url.searchParams.has('redirectTo')) {
            throw redirect(303, url.searchParams.get('redirectTo'));
          }
          //...
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is `redirectTo` supposed to come from? The action is named `login`. So what you get is what I expect. If anything you might get a URL `http://localhost:5173/login?/login&redirectTo=...`, but you need to set that in the form `action` on the page.